# Deny Home-Directory-Access for root

Tags: linux, permissions, root

Hy,
a friend and me want to share a Linux-Machine. We both need to get root-rights via sudo for administering that machine. Is it somehow possible to deny the access to the home-folder for the other one, although he can become root?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only with something like [SELinux](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6836).

Comment: ...and what user account has the right to modify the SELinux rule set?

Comment: A root account with the appropriate role. Simply make it impossible for <friend> to acquire that role.

Answer (score 1):

You could install encrypted home directories. [This page](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7568/2/) has a writeup on how to install under Ubuntu.

Comment: This only protects the data from being mounted for reading.  If the encrypted volume is mounted and both users have root access, they can both read the files within.

Answer (score 1):

you could restrict/deny access to `/bin/su` and other methods of obtaining 'full' root access on the machine. also, you can restrict /what/ can be run with root privileges, for certain users in `/etc/sudoers` and enable full logging of things executed with `sudo`

example:

```
Defaults        logfile=/var/log/sudolog
userA     ALL = (root) /bin/ls, \
                       /usr/bin/apt-get update,  \
                       /usr/bin/vim /etc/*, \
                       !/usr/bin/su *root*
```

and so on. you can provide the exact commands you want your friend to be able to use, including the command line parameters, if you want to lock it down further (like with `apt-get` in my example)

you basically need to figure out /what/ he needs root access for, and dole it out sparingly. or learn to trust him.

two additional examples; vim /etc/* allows the user to edit anything in /etc/ as root, and the last one denies access to `su` (just as an example, since no access to `su` is implied, anyhow.

http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers , the `man 5 sudoers` in web form, has lots of examples to pick over.